# Problem regarding Brownian motion

Tags: random-variables, expectation, brownian-motion

Given $Y(t)=\frac{1}{7}B(49t),\:t\ge0$. $B$ denotes brownian motion position.

Have to show that $E(Y(t)^{2k+1})=0,\:k\in\mathbb{N} $.

So far, I've done showing that $Y(t)$ is a Brownian motion. Then I've tried using the formula for mathematical expectation $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$.

Letting $x\equiv B(49t)$,
$$E(Y(t))=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{7}x\frac{1}{\sqrt t\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x/7}{\sqrt t})^2} dx $$

What to do next to advance?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are on the right track. Can you show that $x$ is an odd function and $\exp(-0.5(x/(7\sqrt{t}))^2)$ is an even function? What happens when you integrate an odd function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @madprob Could you explain in a bit details about integrating odd functions between these limits?

Answer (score 0):

Use induction and integration by parts. Suppose that it is true for k = m. Then (I'm omitting constants that are irrelevant for the final result below):

$F(m) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2m+1} e^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{2m+1}\left( x^{2m+2}e^{-x^2}|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2m+3}e^{-x^2}\right)$

$ = 0 + \frac{1}{2m+1}F(m+1)$

Thus if the result is true for k = m, it is also true for k = m+1. We know that it is true for k = 0, so the result follows.

Comment: Oddness of the integrand is enough to conclude

Comment: @Bananach, Yes, Thank you.

Comment: @skm Isn't the factor in front supposed to be $\frac{1}{2m+2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2m+1}$?

Comment: @Bananach Could you explain?

Comment: @skm Did you use LIATE in your integration by parts?

Comment: @skm How did you evaluate the first term of your integral?

Comment: @BernhardListing Assume $f$ is odd around $0$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=\int_{x>0}f(x)dx+\int_{x<0}f(x)dx=\int_{x>0}f(x)+f(-x)dx=\int_{x>0}f(x)-f(x)=0$